# Error build.gradle with com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In my app I have these dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package_app.name"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
}
```

Below these dependencise I put

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But I can't build app because return this error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.2.0.
```

So I tried to put

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
```

And the app build, so my question is:
**Why I can't use the last versione of services-map**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue yesterday and solved it by doing the follows :

Firstly, make sure that you project/top level gradle file has the latest version for google services inside dependencies

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Secondly, make sure to put the plugin at the bottom of the gradle app file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And make sure all google services dependencies including firebase are of the same version i.e. 9.4.0

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
```

This is what i currently have in my app.gradle dependencies.

Comment: ThankYou! my problem was that not been paying attention to the version of Firebase.

Comment: Glad i was able to help

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to end of `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And add this classpath (other `build.gradle`)

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Comment: There is.
Below dependecies{...}

Comment: Thanks Michele , but There is also classpath in build.gradle but problem persist. I edit my questions with also  other buld.gradle

Comment: You have to update all library to `9.4.0`... but it seemed obvious @LorenzoBerti

Comment: Nothing is obvious! :D thankyou however my problem was that not been paying attention to the version of Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you are using

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
```

As you can find in the pom file of these dependencies:

```
 <artifactId>firebase-analytics</artifactId>
  <version>9.4.0</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
      <artifactId>play-services-basement</artifactId>
      <version>9.2.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
```

they are using the `com.google.android.gms` libraries with 9.2.0.

**Use**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in the root `build.gradle` you have the latest plugin reference.

Also if you recently updated the play services and all references are good - try to clean the gradle cache by calling `rm -rf ~/.gradle/cache`, sometimes it helps

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        //...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this :

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
```

by

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
```

Comment: Downvoted of course, tried this at home and this solve the problem.

Comment: Better Copy/Paste other's response after downvoting i guess, well played