# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'

Tags: android, debugging, runtime-error

I'm getting

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
```

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

**Superior build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    }
}
...
```

**App build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-progressfragment:progressfragment:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.2.0'
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error build.gradle with com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505402/error-build-gradle-with-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-maps9-4-0)

Comment: Thank you. The problem (solved by your link) was that 
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' must be at the bottom of the app build.gradle.

Comment: votes up my answer if you found it useful! :D

Comment: It helped me as well. Post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the bottom of the .gradle as [stated in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase)?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```